# Highcharts error font when display character in a chart

Tags: ubuntu, highcharts, fonts

Timeline in highchart missing ":" to separate hour and minute and title chart must be 10.30.6.95, "9" become "-" in all my chart.

I try to check in the demo in https://www.highcharts.com but it's showing wrong.

I'm using Chrome and Firefox and the chart displayed wrong, so I think the problem can happen in ubuntu fonts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: The error happens on my computer, so I can't reproduce it in any online editor

Comment: I am afraid that this issue is related to integration between the ubuntu environment and this particular font.

Comment: yup, I think so